# What file ownership/permissions should I set for the files/directories before open sourcing a project?

Tags: programming-practices, open-source, permissions

I have multiple projects in different programming languages that I will upload on online code hosting platforms as Open Source projects.

What file permissions and ownerships should I set on the files before uploading them? I work on Linux-platforms. It feels wrong uploading files with permission `MYNAME:MYNAME` as owner and group.

Of course, anyone can change the permissions and ownership to their liking after downloading the project (or maybe they are on other platforms) but is there a best-practice on what to set owner, user and group to initially?

Comment: If you're going to upload this via git then most if this isn't relavent - git doesn't track file ownership, or permissions other than executable. See https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ContentLimitations

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Of course, anyone can change the permissions and ownership to their liking after downloading the project (or maybe they are on other platforms) but is there a best-practice on what to set owner, user and group to initially?

Just leave the ownership to default values. Once someone clones a repository on their machine, they'll become the owner.

Same for permission, go with the default values, unless you plan to include executables in the repository which you can set for user (`u+x`).

Comment: I see, great and thanks for the input